# Indexing lists in python, for a range of values

Tags: python, sequence, slice

To my knowledge, indexing with `-1` will bring you up the last item in a list e.g.

```
list = 'ABCDEFG'
list[-1] 
'G'
```

But when you are asking for a sequence from the list, `-1` gives the second to last term in a list,

```
list[3:-1] 
'DEF'
```

Why? I would have expected, and would like to get `DEFG`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the stop (second) argument of slice notation is exclusive, not inclusive.  So, `[3:-1]` is telling Python to get everything from index `3` up to, but not including, index `-1`.

To get what you want, use `[3:]`:

```
>>> list = 'ABCDEFG'
>>> list[3:]
'DEFG'
>>>
>>> list[3:len(list)]  # This is equivalent to doing:  list[3:]
'DEFG'
>>>
```

---

Also, just a note for the future: it is considered a bad practice to use `list` as a variable name.  Doing so overshadows the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 1):

It's for the same reason that `list[3:4]` doesn't include the character at the 4th index; slicing is not inclusive.  In addition, you can slice from a character to the end simply by omitting the second slice parameter, as in `list[3:]`.